# ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Failed to establish connection

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to ftp upload file using php. Managed to connect via ftp_connect, and ftp_login. That means the connection / credential's ok. However when I try to run ftp_put, it comes out with that error.

```
ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Failed to establish connection
```

Anyone know what could be causing that problem?

Comment: Tried [`ftp_pasv()`](http://php.net/ftp_pasv) when behind a NAT setup and/or firewall?

Comment: It would be nice to actually have the code you used to create that error.